# Uniqueness of the solution of a linear system involving the graph Laplacian

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, pseudoinverse, graph-laplacian

Let $L$ be a Laplacian matrix of a connected graph $G = (V, E)$ and $D$ its degree matrix. Then, for a vector $z \in \mathbb{R}^{|V|}$ and a constant $\rho \in \mathbb{R}$, I have the following:

\begin{equation}
(L + \rho D)x = \rho Dz.
\end{equation}

This [paper](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Emmahoney/pubs/local_pieee.pdf) (page 264) says that, assuming that ${1}^\top_{|V|} Dz = 0$, the above equation has a unique solution. I don't understand why it is so, since it seems to me that $L + \rho D$ isn't always full rank for $\rho \leq 0$. I may be missing something here. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Has probably something to do with 1 being the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue 0 of L. This makes me wonder: are you sure that we don't ask that the graph should be connected?

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo, Yes, but is there a way for to show that $(L+ρD)$ is full rank whenever $\rho \neq  0$? That is not obvious to me when $\rho < 0$. It seems that the information that $1^\top _{|V|}Dz=0$ is useful (or necessary) for that, but how?

Comment: @NeitherNor, yes the graph is assumed to be connected. Sorry, I missed it!

Comment: Just intuition, didn't try it myself: set x=z+y. This gives you $L(z+y)=-\rho D y$, which might or might not be easier

Comment: You may also want to use that $L=L^T$, and that thus the image of L is orthogonal to its kernel. The kernel is span(1), and $1^TDz=0$ thus says that $\rho D z$ is in the image of L...

Comment: @NeitherNor Yes! I had noticed that already, but thanks anyway! I wonder if the authors mean that the pseudo inverse of $L + \rho D$ is unique (as it always is) and that will give an unique solution. Then, the question is: why do they explicitly mention that they need $1^\top_{|V|}Dz=0$ for that?

Comment: in case you have a complete or at least partial answer to your question: answer it yourself. Then, others who might have the same problem and might find your post will benefit, too.

Comment: @NeitherNor Ok! I'll repost that as an answer. Thanks for the advice. I am new around here!

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand better the problem more now. First of all, the matrix $L+ \rho D$ only has a non-trivial null space when $\rho=0$ or $\rho=−\lambda_i(G)$, where $\lambda_i(G)$ is the $i$-th Generalized Eigenvector of $L$ with respect to $D$. Then, the authors of [1](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume13/mahoney12a/mahoney12a.pdf) showed that $\rho >−\lambda_i(G)$, leaving $\rho=0$ to be analysed (remember that $L+ \rho D$ is non singular for $\rho>0$). Now, we are just left to show the uniqueness when $\rho=0$. Maybe we'll use $1^{\top}_{|V|}Dz=0$ here.

Comment: Are you sure there's a $\rho$ in the right-hand side?

Comment: It is weird, I know, but it's on page 264 of this paper i linked on the question. I am considering it to be a typo, but that would be uncommon for the journal it was published on,